# Perl - Code not executing as expected

Tags: perl

I have the following scripts

```
print ("\n\n=========================================\n");

@array = (1,2,"Hello");

print("\$array[0] = $array[0]\n");
print("\$array[1] = $array[1]\n");
print("\$array[2] = $array[2]\n");
@array =(a..z);
**print("\@array[5..10]=@array(5,3..10,24");**
@lenght=@array;
print "The lenght of\@array is:@lenght\n";


print ("=========================================\n\n");.
```

Marked with double `**` were i am not getting expected output. Please help me in solving this.

The output i am  expect is something like this `d,e,f,h,k` something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your desire is to print out specific array elements and the length of the entire array, use something like:

```
@array = ('a'..'z');
$newarray = @array[0,5..10];
print("\@array[0,5..10] = @array[0,5..10]\n");
$length = @array;
print "The length of \@array is $length\n";
```

The output of that is:

```
@array[0,5..10] = a f g h i j k
The length of @array is 26
```

Comment: The `$#` sigill is used to find the index of the last element in the array. Use the array itself in scalar context to find the length: `$length = @array`.

Comment: Also, `a..z` is relying on barewords. It should be `'a'..'z'`.